# Делаю счётчик просмотров к постам, но не ведётся подсчёт

Tags: html, python, django

Делаю счётчик просмотров к статьям с помощью Cookes. При нажатии на пост `view` должно увеличиваться на 1 и отображаться в шаблоне. Вот функция, и я предполагаю что в классе она просто не обрабатывается. Как мне сделать так, чтобы она обрабатывалась, и при этом по нажатию на ссылку поста все свойства `DetailView` открывались статьи по id (pk).

views.py

```
class ArticleDetail(DetailView):
    model = Articles
    template_name = 'news/post.html'


    def addview(request, pk):

        if pk in request.COOKIES:
            response = HttpResponseRedirect('/' % pk)
        else:

            article = get_object_or_404(Articles, id=pk)
            article.view += 1
            article.save()
            response = HttpResponseRedirect('/' % pk)
            response.set_cookie(str(pk), "View")
            return response
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns=[
    path('', ArticleIndex.as_view(), name='articles_list'),
    path('<int:pk>/', ArticleDetail.as_view(), name='article_detail'),
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager

class Articles(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length= 200)
    post = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='', default="default_value")
    tags = TaggableManager()
    article_like = models.IntegerField(default='0')
    article_dislike = models.IntegerField(default='0')
    view = models.IntegerField(default='0')


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Вот так вывожу в шаблон posts.html

```
{% for article in object_list  %}
        <h2> Просмотры: {{ article.view }} </h2>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Проще всего для вас будет посмотреть как работает `DetailView` и вписаться в его метод `get` путем переопределения (не забудьте  `super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)`)

```
def get(request, *args, **kwargs):
    response = super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
    # ваш код с куками
    return response
```